# Return True if the input file contains "?" in every line. Otherwise return false

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I am trying to write a function that would accept filename as a parameter. This function should open the file, read it and return True if the file contains "?" in every line of the text file.
The input file may have the designated character one or more time.
This is what I have so far:

```
def char_finder(filename):
    inputFile = open(filename, "r")
    for line in inputFile:
        if '?' in line:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    inputFile.close

print(char_finder("inputfile.txt"))
```

I have spent several hours looking for every possible similar solution but no results.

Comment: Loop through all lines: if one does *not* contain a `?` (your actual code suggests a `!`), return `False`. Then, at the end of the function, simply return `True`.

Comment: Use the `with` statement to open the file and automatically close it. Note: `inputFile.close` does *not* call the `close` method, hence it doesn't actually close the file.

Comment: And even if it were `inputFile.close()` with the parentheses to actually call the function, it would only be called if the code actually gets to that line. `with` is definitely your friend here. All in all, this is a nice first attempt for a beginning programmer.

Comment: One very important thing: Do you have a Python debugger and know how to use it? You would be able to step through your code line by line and see what it actually does and what the variables contain. It's one of the best learning tools there is. Try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with a [Python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python), or [Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/).

Comment: @MichaelGeary: Thank you for the suggestion. Just started looking at Visual Studio Code with Python extension and its debugging option. It appears that it can be very handy and I think that I will have to learn it though it may take quite some time. Any suggestions how to learn debugging?

Comment: That's great that you are looking into this! One suggestion to start with is to get familiar with the Step In, Step Over, and Step Out functions. (These may have slightly different names in different debuggers, but the concepts will be the same.) To begin with, just use Step In to execute every line of code in your program. When it stops at each line, look around and see what the debugger displays. Usually it will have things like your local and global variables so you can look at their values. Keep using Step In to go through your code and see where it goes and what values it shows.

Comment: Thank you. I have already started practicing. I think that it is extremely useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem you are facing is that you are returning inside your first iteration. The `return` will end execution of your function.

If you are looking to check if all lines contain that '?', then the check should simply be something that will return once it does not find a '?'. If you manage to exhaust your iteration, then all lines have the '?' and you simply return True.

```
def char_finder(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as inputFile:
        for line in inputFile:
            if '?' not in line: 
                return False
    return True
```

Furthermore, notice the reading of the file is now using a context manager, which is a cleaner approach here.

Finally, to refactor this completely, we can make use of the [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function, which will iterate through the each line, and will short circuit once it finds an unmatching condition. It is pretty much exactly what was shown above, but all the work is done for us:

```
def char_finder(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as inputFile:
        return all('?' in line for line in inputFile)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all()` to ensure that all lines passed your condition. For example:

```
def char_finder(filename, char):  # lets make it a bit more universal
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return all(char in line for line in f)

print(char_finder("inputfile.txt", "?"))
```